# Cant get the price (Error list index out of range)

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I have to finish a WebScraping Project for my university, I am scraping from a real estate website and i cant get the price out of it, every other data I needed worked fine. It's writing Error

> list index out of range

but it is the right one I need.

```
var_4 = first.find_all("span", class_="pull-right")[0]
```

https://www.willhaben.at/iad/immobilien/mietwohnungen/niederoesterreich/wiener-neustadt?areaId=304&parent_areaid=3&page=1

That's the link, every price have the same `("span", class_="pull-right")`

I need the price data to analyze the estate for my boxplots and diagrams.

Comment: What's `first` variable?

Comment: its the space in m^2

Comment: You mean the `info` class element?

Comment: i used it to name the process, the var_4 is just my numeric way to write it, like var_1 = first.find_all("span", class_="desc-left")[0].text, and i tried to do the same to the price to create a dataframe but it isnt working

Comment: When you do `first.find_all` you are finding inside the `first` element.

Comment: yeah i am first trying to get the first one(edit it to the right format) and after that i write that code for the whole pages with a string, loop      -for the price its not working thats why i am asking

Answer (score 0):

You can regex the prices. I also extract the `adId` so you can link to id. item['title'] would give you the title. I leave it as a dict so you can look up price by adId.

```
import requests, re, urllib ,json

r = requests.get('https://www.willhaben.at/iad/immobilien/mietwohnungen/niederoesterreich/wiener-neustadt?areaId=304&parent_areaid=3&page=1')
p1 = re.compile(r'var tmsJson = (.*);')
data = json.loads(urllib.parse.unquote(json.loads(p1.findall(r.text)[0])['tmsData']['search_results']))
listings = dict([(item['adId'], item.get('price', 'N/A')) for item in data])
print(listings)
```